# Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 185827(6MB) Error

Tags: java, android, memory-management, garbage-collection, allocation

I am getting this error on fragment

```
Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 185827(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 8(128KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 55MB/61MB, paused 1.007ms total 103.189ms
```

I have implemented adview in Fragment when i am capturing image from camera from that fragment then when result occurs in `OnActivityResult()` then ad is causing a hang in App. I am getting this error on Nexus only. Please share the solution for this.